# How do I change the webroot within a WAMP project?

Tags: wamp, craftcms

I am trying to install Craft CMS locally.

My WAMP is installed and working fine. I can put project folders inside (for example) C:\wamp64\www\projectname

Then I can visit localhost/projectname in my browser to view the index.html

However, Craft CMS has a folder structure like this, whereby the 'web' folder needs to be the webroot:

```
C:\wamp64\www\craft
├── config
│   └── ...
├── modules
│   └── ...
├── storage
│   └── ...
├── templates
│   └── ...
├── vendor
│   └── ...
├── web
│   └── ...
├── .env
├── .env.example
├── .gitignore
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
└── craft
```

How do I configure WAMP so that when I visit my craft project (localhost/craft) that I want it to load C:\wamp64\www\craft\web instead of C:\wamp64\www\craft

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was to set up a virtualhost.

Visit 'localhost', choose 'add virtual; host'

Answer (score 0):

We think this is up to your server.

You need to configure your webserver/virtualhost to point to the /web directory.

For apache, you have DocumentRoot: your_disk_path/web

For Nginx you have root: your_disk_path/web